# Openerp add fields in invoice

Tags: odoo, invoice

![openerp invoice][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6zY0.pngemphasized text

I would like to add discount ammount to my invoice template not in percents but in real ammount

Example:  item value 100$,  discout 10%,  discount is 10$

i need to put it in a template like in the picture above

Answer (score 0):

The account_invoice_line class in OpenERP is designed in such way to consider the discount field as percent. If you need discounts in absolute value you need to customize the account module and modify the account.invoice.line object. Maybe the easiest is to add another filed - let say abs_discount, and to take it with priority, if present.

You should look at least at the methods _ammount_line(), _price_unit_default(), move_line_get() and compute() of the account_invoice_line class.

You should also modify the Invoice view to allow the editing of the new field.